# Multiple mule-app.properties when building mule esb zip

Tags: java, maven, mule

I am having an issue when I do a maven clean install on my mule 3.4 project. It will generate the following directory structure inside the deployable zip:

```
ZIPFile.zip
    ->mule-app.properties
    ->mule-deploy.properties
    ->project.xml
    ->classes->mule-app.properties
    ->classes->mule-deploy.properties
    ->lib->various libraries
```

As you can see, the archive will end up with multiple mule-*.properties which causes confusion on the deployment server.
Has anyone else had this problem when creating the deployable archive and how did you fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Hello, using https://github.com/mulesoft/maven-mule-plugin, if I put mule-app.properties in src/main/resources I end up with that file only in classes directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with the Build Helper Maven Plugin, as described in [this blog post](http://poznachowski.blogspot.fi/2013/11/handling-groovy-scripts-in-mule-esb.html). If you see this plugin configuration section in your generated pom.xml, try removing it.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed was the problem.